# How to send model data via ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.Net MVC 5 project I have a cshtml file and it has one view model. Now in the view model I have a string variable called `Temp` which I need to pass to ajax call.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#Hello" ).blur(function() {
            var x = $('#Site').val();
            var e = @Model.Temp; // Here I get the value in developer tool but it says "Uncaught Reference Error type: undefined"
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Settings/CheckPrefix',
                data: { Prefix: x , Site: e },
                success: function (data) {   
                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I capture the Temp variable in script and send it to ajax call. I can see the value of `TEMP` in the developer tool. [image]

**EDIT**

Ok I did some thing like below

```
var e = "@Model.Temp";
```

I am beginner I am  not sure if this is the right way. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically, all you need to do is surround it with quotes so that once it's rendered by Razor server-side, it doesn't create a JS syntax error client-side:

```
var e = '@Model.Temp';
```

The way you have it now, the contents of the variable are dumped directly in the JS code. For example if `Model.Temp` was `"foo"`, then your rendered JS code would look like:

```
var e = foo;
```

Then, because `foo` is not defined as variable in your JS, you get a syntax error. Whereas, with the quotes, you'd get:

```
var e = 'foo';
```

Making it just a JS string, and perfectly fine.

However, this is not very robust and requires you to keep the script in your view. It would be better to create a namespaced JavaScript variable and then use that later in your JS code:

```
<script>
    var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
    MyNamespace.MyVariable = '@Model.Temp';
</script>

<!-- other JS code, preferably loaded externally rather than inline -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the namespace answer. It is really helpful. I learned something interesting and new today. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need quotes around the variable in Razor:

```
var e = "@Model.Temp";
```